# How to match n items from a list in regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match n elements from a list of items:

```
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,twenty,thirty,forty,fifty,sixty,seventy,eighty,ninety,hundred,thousands,million,billion
```

I want to check how many of items from the above list is present in a string. How can achieve that?

For example, I want to check that whether a string contains any 6 from the list:

```
(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety|hundred|thousands|million|billion){6}
```

Comment: Have a look on my edits. :)

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I dont think this is a job for regex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add wildcards that will consume the tokens you don't want to match :

```
(\b(?:one|two|three|four|[...]|thousands|million|billion)\b.*){6}
```

That way you will match 6 occurrences of the searched tokens, and anything that stands between.

I've also added word-boundaries (`\b`) in order to avoid matching parts of words ("one" in "honest").

Note that you can't make sure that there isn't more than 6 searched tokens, because even with anchors the extra tokens would be consumed by the `.*`. However, this will not match if there is less than 6 searched tokens.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3IvEWf/1) courtesy of [Rad Lexus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/rad-lexus).

Comment: @RadLexus nice, I'll include a link in my answer. Good idea to use `\b` too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It would be better if you could add some explanation too, for a beginner like me.

Comment: @learner I thought I did a good job explaining how the 6 tokens are now matched. What exactly would you want explanation about?